# why sqrt() and abs() work in C program without including math.h or stdlib.h?

Tags: c

Below is some of my code in C. As you can see the only header I'm including is `stdio.h`. However, I get a warning that `abs` has a conflicting declaration:
`note: 'abs' is a builtin with type 'int (int)'` and `sqrt` works without using my function.

My compiler version: `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)`.

Compilation flags I'm using: `-Wall -pedantic -ansi`.

How can this be?

```
#include <stdio.h>

double abs(double x) {
    return x >= 0 ? x : -x;
}

double sqrt(double y) {
    double x = 1.0;
    int error;
    printf("My sqrt\n");
    if(y <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    while(abs(error = y - x * x) > .0005) {
        x = x + error/ (2 * x);
    }
    return x;

}

int main() {
    printf("sqrt(%d) = %8.3f\n", 2, sqrt(2.0));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your compiler's stdio.h is including stdlib, or perhaps providing its own declaration of `abs`. Can you update your post to show the warning?

Comment: a clarification .. `stdio.h` is a header file, not a library. You include header files and link to libraries.

Comment: @AustinHastings updated with the warning message.

Comment: That's because your compiler, by default, is not a Standard C compiler, but very likely a compiler for "a language similar to C but with extensions some group of people believe are a good idea". You should provide us with the name of compiler and the exact options you compile your source file with.

Comment: @Jens added those details

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some compilers like gcc have "[**builtins**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)" (sometimes called "compiler intrinsics, I think) which I think they provide for optimization. This is why you may be able to use these functions without having to link against `libm`.

> Compiler intrinsics (sometimes called "builtins") are like the library functions you're used to, except they're built in to the compiler. They may be faster than regular library functions [**[Ref]**](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/introduction-gcc-compiler-intrinsics-vector-processing)

From the GCC page (linked above):

> The ISO C90 functions ... abs, ... sqrt, ... are all recognized as built-in functions unless -fno-builtin is specified ... All of these functions have corresponding versions prefixed with __builtin_.

As others have pointed out, you're also declaring these functions yourself. The names you give these functions "collide" with the names of the builtins. This is why you see `note: 'abs' is a builtin with type 'int (int)'` and why when you remove your functions the symbols are still valid.

Comment: Another piece of the puzzle: `sqrt` would normally require linking with libm (`-lm`). However `sqrt(2.0)` can be optimized to `1.4142...` at compile time and so linking with libm is not necessary.

Comment: Mac is sensible and includes all the functions for the standard C library in the standard C library so there is no need for a separate mathematics library. The separate mathematics library is a relic from the days when FPUs were not always available. They provide little benefit to modern systems.

Answer (score 1):

You declared and defined those functions on your own. 
Those functions are also declared in `math.h`, however you don't include that header file, so you can simply declare it on your own.

Comment: `abs()` is not typically in `<math.h>` as it is an integer function.  Perhaps you are thinking of `fabs()`?

Answer (score 1):

ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.1.3 **Reserved identifiers** says:

> ¶1 Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and
>   optionally declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated future library directions
>   subclause and identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as file
>   scope identifiers.
>
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
>     underscore are always reserved for any use.
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
>     with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.
> - Each macro name in any of the following subclauses (including the future library
>     directions) is reserved for use as specified if any of its associated headers is included;
>     unless explicitly stated otherwise (see 7.1.4).
> - All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the
>     future library directions) and errno are always reserved for use as identifiers with
>     external linkage.<sup>184)</sup>
> - Each identifier with file scope listed in any of the following subclauses (including the
>     future library directions) is reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with
>     file scope in the same name space if any of its associated headers is included.
>
> ¶2 No other identifiers are reserved. If the program declares or defines an identifier in a
>   context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved
>   identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.
>
> <sup>184)</sup> The list of reserved identifiers with external linkage includes `math_errhandling`, `setjmp`,
>   `va_copy`, and `va_end`.

I think that a strict reading of that, especially the 'all identifiers with external linkage' bullet point, means that when you write functions with names that are reserved identifiers (`abs()` and `sqrt()`), you are invoking undefined behaviour — so any result is feasible.